# How to avoid my own nuget package overwrite the target project web.config and global.aspx file when they install my package

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I was created one nuget package using following step.

1. First I created one Asp.net Mvc application
2. The I created spec file using nuget spec command
3. Then I edited $id$,$version$,$author$,$description$ ect..
4. Then I created package using following command.
5. nuget pack myproject.csproj -Build -Properties Configuration=Release
6. It was created one myproject.1.0.0.0.nupkg
7. Then I copy the file And past into C:\LocalNuGetFeed\myproject.1.0.0.0.nupkg
8. I already configure the local repository in my VS

**My problem is** 
When I install this package from any other project it ask following question.
But as per my requirement I don't want to move this file to target project.  Suppose user give **y** the it overwrite the target project file because of it i face lot reference problem.

```
**File Conflict
File 'Web.config' already exists in project 'CRM'. Do you want to overwrite it?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "N"): 

File Conflict
File 'Global.asax' already exists in project 'CRM'. Do you want to overwrite it?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "N"):**
```

But in my package I don't want to move this above two file from package to target project.

Is any way to avoid transform Global.asax and Web.config move from package to target project.

In my .nuspec file I added following line

```
<files>  
     <file src="Web.config" target = "" exclude="Web.config"/> 
    <file src="*.asax" target = "" exclude="*.asax"/>
    <file src="Content\*.css" target="Content\" />
    <file src="Scripts\*.js" target="Content\Scripts\" />
  </files>
```

But it include the **web.config** file AND **Global.aspx** file in Content folder My resultant package look like bellow

```
myproject.1.0.0.0
      >> Content
           ....css
           >>Script
                ..Js file
           web.config
           Global.asax
```

Comment: Don't include that stuff in your package in the first place?

Comment: Please give any sample how to exclude file

Answer (score 1):

I was solved this using following command to crate package

```
nuget pack CrmHtmlController.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Exclude **\*.config;**\*.asax
```

so it exclude all .congig and .asax file from package.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your .nuspec file. It's just an XML file, so you can open it up with any text editor. See how it define which files to include at `<package><files>`? Remove those files that you don't want. A handy tool if you want to do this with a GUI is [NuGet Package Manager](https://npe.codeplex.com/).

Comment: <files>
    <file src="Content\*.css" target="Content\" />
    <file src="Scripts\*.js" target="Content\Scripts\" />
  </files>

Answer (score 0):

Nuget includes the web.config in your package, because the build action of the web.config is "Content". This is by default and necessary for a classic publish of an asp.net web site.

If you don't want this, propably because your assembly is only a component of another web site, you can change the build action to "None" and nuget will not take it any longer.